# How many domains can be associated with an EC2 instance simultaneously?

Tags: amazon-ec2, domain, multiple-instances

How many domains can be associated simultaneously with an EC2 instance which runs on windows 2012 Server with SQL Web ?

We have 5*n domain names to host on these servers, n stands for number of versions we run parallel to each other..

Comment: Make sure you clear up what you're asking. Are you asking how many domains one EC2 can handle? If so the other information (windows, SQL etc) is not important. Are you asking for capacity planning information? If so, that's going to be tough to answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can point as many domains as you want at an EC2 instance.  The question really is, how many virtual servers can you host off of the EC2 instance or instances you are running?

You haven't specified the instance type.  And even if you had, some of them come with unpredictable performance (great one moment, poor the next due to it sharing resources with other virtual machines on the same physical machine).  Don't use anything less than a large or xlarge instance for windows as you will end up sharing the hardware with less tenants the bigger the instance type.

In any case, you can host your domains on multiple EC2 instances and use the Load Balance feature to spread your workload across multiple EC2 instances.  Provided of course your website is set up with this in mind.